# Understanding tree structure in R gbm package

Tags: r, tree, gbm

I am having some difficulty understanding how the trees are structured in R's gbm gradient boosted machine package.  Specifically, looking at the output of the `pretty.gbm.tree` **Which features do the indices in `SplitVar` point to**?

I trained a GBM on a dataset, here is the top ~quarter of one of my trees -- the result of a call to `pretty.gbm.tree`:

````
   SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight   Prediction
0         9  6.250000e+01        1         2          21      0.6634681   5981  0.005000061
1        -1  1.895699e-12       -1        -1          -1      0.0000000   3013  0.018956988
2        31  4.462500e+02        3         4          20      1.0083722   2968 -0.009168477
3        -1  1.388483e-22       -1        -1          -1      0.0000000   1430  0.013884830
4        38  5.500000e+00        5        18          19      1.5748155   1538 -0.030602956
5        24  7.530000e+03        6        13          17      2.8329899    361 -0.078738904
6        41  2.750000e+01        7        11          12      2.2499063    334 -0.064752766
7        28 -3.155000e+02        8         9          10      1.5516610     57 -0.243675567
8        -1 -3.379312e-11       -1        -1          -1      0.0000000     45 -0.337931219
9        -1  1.922333e-10       -1        -1          -1      0.0000000     12  0.109783128
```
````

It looks to me here that the indices are 0 based, from looking at how `LeftNode, RightNode`, and `MissingNode` point to different rows.  When testing this out by using data samples and following it down the tree to their prediction, I get the correct answer when I consider `SplitVar` to be using **1 based indexing**.

However, 1 of the many trees I build has a *zero* in the `SplitVar` column!  Here is this tree:

```
SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight    Prediction
0         4  1.462500e+02        1         2          21      0.41887   5981  0.0021651262
1        -1  4.117688e-22       -1        -1          -1      0.00000    512  0.0411768781
2         4  1.472500e+02        3         4          20      1.05222   5469 -0.0014870985
3        -1 -2.062798e-11       -1        -1          -1      0.00000     23 -0.2062797579
4         0  4.750000e+00        5         6          19      0.65424   5446 -0.0006222011
5        -1  3.564879e-23       -1        -1          -1      0.00000   4897  0.0035648788
6        28 -3.195000e+02        7        11          18      1.39452    549 -0.0379703437
```

**What is the correct way to view the indexing used by gbm's trees?**

Comment: It would help if you included a small [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the code you are using to generate your objects. Showing just the results does not allow us to get a good idea of what's going on. Vectors in R are always 1-based. An unnamed first column is usually a row name rather than an index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first column that is printed when you use the `pretty.gbm.tree` is the `row.names` that is assigned in the script `pretty.gbm.tree.R`. In the script, the `row.names` is assigned as `row.names(temp) <- 0:(nrow(temp)-1)` where `temp` is the tree information stored in `data.frame` form. The right way to interpret the `row.names` is to read it as the `node_id` with the root node being assigned a 0 value.

In your example:

`Id SplitVar SplitCodePred LeftNode RightNode MissingNode ErrorReduction Weight   Prediction
0         9  6.250000e+01        1         2          21      0.6634681   5981  0.005000061`

means that the root node (indicated by the row number 0) is split by the 9-th split variable (the numbering of the split variable here starts from 0, so the split variable is the 10th column in the training set `x`). `SplitCodePred` of `6.25` denotes that all points less than `6.25` went to the `LeftNode 1` and all points greater than `6.25` went to `RightNode 2`. All points that had a missing value in this column were assigned to the `MissingNode 21`. The `ErrorReduction` was `0.6634` due to this split and there were 5981 (`Weight`) in the root node. `Prediction` of `0.005` denotes the value assigned to all values at this node before the point was split. In the case of terminal nodes (or leaves) denoted by `-1` in `SplitVar`, `LeftNode`, `RightNode`, and `MissingNode`, the `Prediction` denotes the value predicted for all the points belonging to this leaf node adjusted (times) times the `shrinkage`.

To understand the tree structure, its important to note that the splitting of the tree happens in a depth first fashion. So when the root node (with node id 0) is split into its left node and right node, the left side is processed until no further splits are possible before returning and labeling the right node. In both the trees in your example, the `RightNode` gets a value of 2. This is because in both cases, the `LeftNode` turns out to be a leaf node.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that points exactly equal to 6.25 go right.

Comment: I believe 6.250000e+01 is 62.5, not 6.25.