# how to extract coefficients in logistic regression using gbm?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, gbm

I am using the gbm package for generalized boosted regression models, 
and would like to be able to extract the coefficients produced for 
storage in a database.

I am already using R to automatically generate formulas that I can 
export to a database and store. For example, I have been using Dr. 
Harrell's lrm package to perform logistic regression, e.g.:

```
output <- lrm(outcome~predictor1+predictor2,data=dataset) 
cat(output$coefficients)
```

Is it possible to do this with gbm? I know gbm gives a number of trees linearly combined by weights but is there any possibility that I get each of the tree printed? Or is it perhaps at least possible to do so in the case where interaction.depth=1 (e.g., no interactions are allowed)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The following would make it easier to help you: Provide a small, reproducable example that uses `gbm`. Then explain which part of the object you want to save and/or what you'd like to do with the saved data afterwards.

Comment: Suggestion: examine `dput(output)` for your `gbm` object. The coefficients are bound to be stored in there somewhere.

Comment: @MichaelChirico tried it but there's terribly many outputs.. totally don't know what they mean lol

Answer (score 1):

GBM's (and other tree-based models) don't have coefficients so there isn't anything to extract. Are you trying to score a database using your `gbm` object? If so you have two options: 1) Encode each of the `gbm` trees as SQL queries 2) Pull the data into R, score it, and write it back to the database.

Comment: actually I am analyzing how variables impact the dependent variable and do prediction in that data so i have to see how the trees are like if it's tree-based..

Comment: At their core, the trees are just a series of if else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pretty.gbm.tree` function to look at the tree structure:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf

There are more details about the output here:
[Understanding tree structure in R gbm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296541/understanding-tree-structure-in-r-gbm-package?rq=1)